# Zero equality in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, math

Why do these two equalities produce two different results in Python? I'm not sure why the first one outputs a zero; I was expecting a `True`.

```
>>> 0 and 2 >= 0
0
>>> 2 and 0 >= 0
True
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the first is parsed as

```
(0) and (2 >= 0)   # 0 evaluates to False
```

Which is evaluated to

```
0 and True
```

Which is

```
0
```

Similarly the second is

```
(2) and (0 >= 0)   # any non-zero digit is evaluated to True
```

Which is evaluated to

```
True and True
```

Which is

```
True
```

If you are trying to evaluate both digits, you could do

```
>>> 0 >= 0 and 2 >= 0
True
```

Or for many digits if you want to check against some criteria

```
>>> l = [1,4,6,2,7,3]
>>> all(i >= 0 for i in l)
True
```

Comment: But the first outputs 0, not False.

Comment: `(0) and (2 >= 0)` is *not* equivalent to `False and True`.

Comment: `(0) and (2 >= 0)` is not evaluated to `False and True` but `0 and True`. In fact, only `0` is evaluated due to short circuiting the expression.

Comment: @delnan that's because Python returns the value that decides the boolean expression's result. This allows things like `config or default`: in a boolean context this will be converted to a `bool` via `__bool__` (Py3) or `__nonzero__` (Py2).

Answer (score 1):

[According to reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) `x and y` is evaluated as `if x is false, then x, else y`. So it returns the first value *without* conversion to `bool` type. And the first value is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> 2 >= 0
True
>>> 0 and True
0
>>> False and True
False
```

First it evaluates the expression 2 >= 0 then 0 and True.
As in python 0 is equivalent to False that is why **anding** 0 and True gives result 0

```
>>> 2 and 0 >= 0
True
>>> 0 >= 0
True
>>> 2 and True
True
>>>
```

The same way here 2 which is greater than 0 is equivalent True. and **anding** them gives result True

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing the short-circuiting of the `and` operator.  If the first operand does not evaluate to a truth value, then the first value is returned verbatim.

Compare `0 and 0` to `False and False`